# Conditional V-HTML rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Just wondering if there is something I'm missing here:

```
<span v-html="(shouldParseHTMLBool ? HTMLContent : '')">
  {{ contentWithoutParsedHTML }}
</span>
```

doens't appear to work.

I would like to have this `span` interpreting HTML only if `shouldParseHTMLBool` is set to `true`.

Is it something possible, or should I use a `v-if`? In this trivial example it's not a big deal, but with my components I'll have to duplicate ~30 lines for each condition.

Comment: `v-html` is going to replace whatever is in the element with it's value.  So it would make more sense for the `contentWithoutParsedHTML` to be in the place of `HTMLContent`, or as the else of the ternary

Answer (score 2):

It's better to make if condition away from template as much as possible.
You should create a computed object instead.

[template]

```
<span v-html="computedContent"></span>
```

[script]

```
...
computed: {
  computedContent: function () {
    return this.shouldParseHTMLBool ? this.HTMLContent : ''
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `v-html` directive replaces the innerHTML of the element. In your case, the `{{ contentWithoutParsedHTML }}` will be replaced with the value of `(shouldParseHTMLBool ? HTMLContent : '')`

You can do something like

```
<template>
<span v-html="conditionalParse"></span>
</template>
<script>
methods: {
conditionalParse: function () {
    return this.shouldParseHTMLBool ? this.HTMLContent : ''
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<span v-if="shouldParseHTMLBool" v-html="HTMLContentForIfCondition" >All</span>
<span v-else v-html="HTMLContentForElseCondition" ></span>
```

You can use two spans, One for v-if is true and other for v-else